# Save images for my web server in SPIFFS on esp32-S2

Tags: webserver, esp32, arduino-ide, spiffs

Hi it's my first time using esp32-S2 because now its not recommended to use esp32. I'm looking for saving images in SPIFFS for my web server. In esp32 i used to use esp32fs plugin (https://github.com/me-no-dev/arduino-esp32fs-plugin) but it doesn't work for esp32-S2. I would like to know if there is any plugin like esp32fs and if not how can i save my images (I'm using arduinoIDE 1.8.19). I've been searching but i didn't found anything. Any orientation is welcomed. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [**ESP32_FSWebServer_DRD**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP_WiFiManager/tree/master/examples/ESP32_FSWebServer_DRD) or [**ESP_FSWebServer**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP_WiFiManager/tree/master/examples/ESP_FSWebServer) example of [**ESP_WiFiManager**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP_WiFiManager) library

Follow the instructions in [ESP_FSWebServer Example](https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP_WiFiManager/tree/master/examples/ESP_FSWebServer#esp_fswebserver-example)

You can use either `deprecated` SPIFFS or the better LittleFS